# Partial matching string in R

Tags: r

I have a data with 2 variables `var` and `text`. I need to remove the partial matching from `text` and save it. I have the sample of the result.

```
dt <- data.frame(var  = c("OCILY10","SUDHL16","u2932"), 
                 text = c("OCILY-10-Cas9_T12", "SU-DHL-16_T12_vs_T0","U2932_T10-122-SEMI-A"))

> dt 
      var                 text
1 OCILY10    OCILY-10-Cas9_T12
2 SUDHL16  SU-DHL-16_T12_vs_T0
3   u2932 U2932_T10-122-SEMI-A

#======================
# Result 

dt <- data.frame(var  = c("OCILY10","SUDHL16","u2932"),
                 text = c("OCILY-10-Cas9_T12", "SU-DHL-16_T12_vs_T0","U2932_T10-122-SEMI-A"),
                 result = c("Cas9_T12", "T12_vs_T0","T10-122-SEMI-A"))


> dt
      var                 text         result
1 OCILY10    OCILY-10-Cas9_T12       Cas9_T12
2 SUDHL16  SU-DHL-16_T12_vs_T0      T12_vs_T0
3   u2932 U2932_T10-122-SEMI-A T10-122-SEMI-A
```

Comment: Are these the only patterns i.e. it works with the regex `dt %>% mutate(result = trimws(str_remove(text, toupper(str_replace(var, "^(..).*(..)$", "\\1.*\\2"))), whitespace = "[-_]"))`

Comment: Is there any regularity to whether there is a dash or an underscore?

Comment: sometimes it has underscore, or dash, some special characters

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing from @Akrun's comment, here's a `dplyr` solution in steps:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
dt %>%
  mutate(
    # create temporary column with two first and two last characters from `var`;
    # add `.*` between them as regex metacharacters (@Akrun's ingenious idea!):
    temp = str_replace(var, "^(..).*(..)$", "\\1.*\\2"),
    # make `temp` a case-insensitive pattern und replace what it matches in `text` with nothing:
    result = str_replace(text, paste0("(?i)", temp), ""),
    # remove leading `-` and `_`:
    result = str_replace(result, "^(-|_)", "")) %>%
  # remove temporary column:
  select(-temp)
      var                 text         result
1 OCILY10    OCILY-10-Cas9_T12       Cas9_T12
2 SUDHL16  SU-DHL-16_T12_vs_T0      T12_vs_T0
3   u2932 U2932_T10-122-SEMI-A T10-122-SEMI-A
```

**EDIT**:

To account for more variability in `text` (as per comment by OP) here's an edited solution:

```
dt %>%
  mutate(
    # create temporary column with two first and two last characters from `var`;
    # add `[^_]*` between them as a negative character class:
    temp = str_replace(var, "^(..).*(.)$", "\\1[^_]*\\2"),
    # make `temp` a case-insensitive pattern und replace what it matches in `text` with nothing:
    result = str_replace(text, paste0("(?i)", temp), ""),
    # remove leading `-` and `_`:
    result = str_replace(result, "^(-|_)", "")) %>%
  # remove temporary column:
  select(-temp)
      var                 text         result
1 OCILY10    OCILY-10-Cas9_T12       Cas9_T12
2 SUDHL16  SU-DHL-16_T12_vs_T0      T12_vs_T0
3   u2932 U2932_T10-122-SEMI-A T10-122-SEMI-A
4  SUDHL2   SU-DHL-2_T12_vs_T0      T12_vs_T0
5  SUDHL4   SU-DHL-4_T12_vs_T0      T12_vs_T0
```

Data:

```
dt <- data.frame(var  = c("OCILY10","SUDHL16","u2932", "SUDHL2", "SUDHL4"),                   
                 text = c("OCILY-10-Cas9_T12", "SU-DHL-16_T12_vs_T0","U2932_T10-122-SEMI-A","SU-DHL-2_T12_vs_T0","SU-DHL-4_T12_vs_T0"))
```

**EDIT 2**:

To allow for even greater variability (namely variation in upper v. lower case and also variation in use of hyphen and underscore), here's another solution:

Data:

```
dt <- data.frame(var  = c("ABCD10","KQRqS17","y7854", "PGRS2", "PGRS4"),                   
                 text = c("AB_cd-10-Cas9_T12", "KQ-RqS-17_T12_vs_T0",
                          "Y_7-854_T10-122-SEMI-A","P-GRS-2_T12_vs_T0","pg-RS-4_T12_vs_T0"))
```

Solution:

```
dt %>%
  mutate(
    # make a first temporary column without any `-` or `_`:
    temp_1 = str_replace_all(text, "[-_]", ""),
    # make a second temporary column by making `var` a case-insensitive pattern 
    # and replace its matches in `temp_1` with nothing,
    # thereby removing anything but the ultimate `result`:
    temp_2 = str_replace(temp_1, paste0("(?i)", var), ""),
    # make a third temporary column containing just the first three characters from the ultimate `result`
    temp_3 = str_replace(temp_2, "^(...).*", "\\1"),
    # match `temp_3` in `text` and recollect the matches plus anything that follows the matches:
    result =  str_replace(text, paste0(".*(", temp_3, ".*)$"), "\\1")) %>%
  # remove temporary columns:
  select(-matches("temp"))
          var                   text         result
    1  ABCD10      AB_cd-10-Cas9_T12       Cas9_T12
    2 KQRqS17    KQ-RqS-17_T12_vs_T0      T12_vs_T0
    3   y7854 Y_7-854_T10-122-SEMI-A T10-122-SEMI-A
    4   PGRS2      P-GRS-2_T12_vs_T0      T12_vs_T0
    5   PGRS4      pg-RS-4_T12_vs_T0      T12_vs_T0
```

Comment: for some reason if I add 2 more cases, it didn't work ```dt <- data.frame(var  = c("OCILY10","SUDHL16","u2932", "SUDHL2", "SUDHL4"), 
                 text = c("OCILY-10-Cas9_T12", "SU-DHL-16_T12_vs_T0","U2932_T10-122-SEMI-A","SU-DHL-2_T12_vs_T0","SU-DHL-4_T12_vs_T0"))
```

Comment: Please check out edited answer-does this work?

Comment: Have added yet another solution allowing for even greater variability.

Answer (score 2):

Another tidyverse solution.

```
library(tidyverse)

dt %>%
  mutate(split = str_split(text, '(?<=[_-])')) %>%
  unnest(split) %>%
  mutate(sieve = str_remove(split, '_|-')) %>%
  filter(!str_detect(var, str_c('(?i)', sieve))) %>%
  group_by(var) %>%
  mutate(result = str_c(split, collapse = '')) %>%
  distinct(var, text, result)

# # A tibble: 3 x 3
# # Groups:   var [3]
#   var     text                 result        
#   <chr>   <chr>                <chr>         
# 1 OCILY10 OCILY-10-Cas9_T12    Cas9_T12      
# 2 SUDHL16 SU-DHL-16_T12_vs_T0  T12_vs_T0     
# 3 u2932   U2932_T10-122-SEMI-A T10-122-SEMI-A
```

Comment: That's a very cool solution - bravo!

Comment: Thank you for the kind words, @ChrisRuehlemann. As I see it, both ```split``` and ```sieve``` are required. ```split``` retains the necessary information regarding hyphens/underscores, while ```sieve``` is needed for filtering ```split``` (which is then reassembled in groups). Of course, the making of ```sieve``` can be done on the fly (inside ```filter()```), but IMO that would entail a fairly long and illegible line.

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann: Sure, but that outputs a ```result``` without hyphens and underscores. Again, we loose the information.

Comment: Yes, you are right! Sorry for the oversight. So you solution is perfect. @Ben, If I were the OP I'd accept it.